# Cygwin SSH and Github

Tags: windows-8, ssh, cygwin

I've been trying to setup Cygwin to connect to github, but I've been having some issues. I'm on Windows 8, and I know that there's a problem in Cygwin on Windows 8 with the user groups and whatnot. I'm pretty sure I've fixed that already though. At the very least, I can change the permissions for any file properly now. Anyways, this is the output I get from Cygwin

```
ssh -vT git@github.com

OpenSSH_6.2p2, OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Connecting to github.com [204.232.175.90] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-6+squeeze1+github12
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-6+squeeze1+github12 pat OpenSSH_5*
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 16:27:ac:a5:76:28:2d:36:63:1b:56:4d:eb:df:a6:48
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Something interesting when I run this:

```
$ ssh-add -l
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
```

I'll also point out that I can use git just fine on Powershell.

Comment: Does the output of `ssh-keygen -lf ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` match the key signature in github? 
[source](https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey#verify-the-public-key-is-attached-to-your-github-account)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It maybe that your ssh-agent is started from your PowerShell startup files. That's probably why it works there.

The simpler fix is to start another agent. You can use [PuTTY's Pageant](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html). Check here how to configure your shell to setup connection to Pageant so that ssh-add and ssh will use it:
http://pascal.nextrem.ch/2011/03/11/using-cygwin-ssh-with-putty-pageant/